# Multiple Gestures dont seem to be working (*CustomGestureRecognizer and UILongPressGestureRecognizer)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uigesturerecognizer

I've made a custom gesture recognizer and im adding it to my customView .
The custom gesture is a subclass of UIPanGestureRecognizer .

The other gesture that im adding is LongPressGestureRecognizer

```
                    CustomGestureRecognizer *pan;
                pan = [[CustomGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[self viewController] action:@selector(dragImage:)];
                [pan setDirection:DirectionPangestureRecognizerVertical];
                [pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
                [pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
                [custom addSubview:custom.imageView];
                [custom addGestureRecognizer:pan];
                [pan release];

                UILongPressGestureRecognizer *highLight = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:[self viewController] 
                                                                                            action:@selector(highlightImage:)];
                [highLight setDelaysTouchesBegan:0.1];
                [tempView addGestureRecognizer:highLight];
                [highLight release];
```

Also i have implemented

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (![gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]] && ![otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) 
    {
        return YES;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Both im my [self viewController] and in the self class but im still not getting both the gesture to work simultaniiosly .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the delegates of your gesture recognizers...that method will never be called.